# Convert content of vector into word java

Tags: java

I'm trying to return and output the contents of a vector as a cohesive String. I tried `vector.toString()` but that would also include brackets and commas. I can't have that. Is there a way to convert just the elements of that vector into a String?

Comment: Help us help you - please provide a sample of such a vector and the result you'd lie to get for it

Comment: @Merna George: Welcome to StackOverflow..!! Please post question outlining your problem and detailing what you have tried and what you are struggling to achieve with some examples if required.

Answer (score 1):

- You can do this by using apache StringUtils:

  ```
  import java.util.Vector;

  import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

  public class VectorExample {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Vector<String> vector=  new Vector<String>();
    vector.add("test1");
    vector.add("test2");
    vector.add("test3");

    System.out.println(StringUtils.join(vector, " "));
   }
  }
  ```

Output: test1 test2 test3

- I would suggest adding a new method like getElementsAsString() in a utility/helper class or into the class where you have created/processing the vector, which will get you the string in the format you want.
- If you want to stick to and use only the toString() method, extending the Vector is an option. Then you can override the toString() method.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're using Java 8+ then you don't have to pull in a dependency for this, just use [`String#join(CharSequence,Iterable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.Iterable)).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Vector<Integer> vector = new Vector<Integer>();
        vector.add(1);
        vector.add(2);
        vector.add(3);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        vector.forEach(n -> sb.append(String.valueOf(n)));
        String str = sb.toString();

        System.out.println(sb);
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
123
123
```

---

**Alternatively,**

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Vector<Integer> vector = new Vector<Integer>();
        vector.add(1);
        vector.add(2);
        vector.add(3);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int n : vector) {
            sb.append(n);
        }
        String str = sb.toString();

        System.out.println(sb);
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
123
123
```

---

**Alternatively,**

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Vector<Integer> vector = new Vector<Integer>();
        vector.add(1);
        vector.add(2);
        vector.add(3);

        String str = "";
        for (int n : vector) {
            str += n;
        }

        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
123
```

**Note:** *This approach should be discouraged because it will create as many String objects as the number of iterations.*

---

**Alternatively,**

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Vector<Integer> vector = new Vector<Integer>();
        vector.add(1);
        vector.add(2);
        vector.add(3);

        String str = vector.toString().replaceAll(",|\\[|\\]|\\s+", "");

        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
123
```

---

If the elements of the `Vector` are `String`, you can also do the following:

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Vector<String> vector = new Vector<String>();
        vector.add("1");
        vector.add("2");
        vector.add("3");

        String str = String.join("", vector);

        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
123
```

Comment: No reason to create a `Stream` from the `Vector` if all you're going to do is `forEach`, just use `vector.forEach(...)` directly.